# Multiple traits method call this property

Tags: php, oop

```
trait a
{
   private $url = 123;

   public function foo()
   {
       echo $this->url;
   }

}

trait b
{
   private $url = 456;

   public function foo()
   {
       echo $this->url;
   }
}


class Foo
{
   use a, b {
      a::$url insteadof $aUrl;
      b::$url as $bUrl;
      a::foo insteadof aFoo;
      b::foo as bFoo;
   }

}
```

I have 2 traits, both trait contain same properties & methods name

One of my class required use these 2 traits

I try to alias to different name.

My question is inside of method foo, it execute $this->url;

Will this cause problem? because which trait url now?

Comment: i got error on alias property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can change your OOP architecture ? Use abstract classes or interfaces instead of trait for this ? It's better not using properties inside Trait...